# Why is sys.maxint < (sys.maxint - 100 + 0.01) in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point

Why is sys.maxint < (sys.maxint - 100 + 0.01) in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a system with 64-bit longs, `sys.maxint` is:

```
// decimal                  hexadecimal
   9223372036854775807      0x7fffffffffffffff
```

So `sys.maxint - 100` is:

```
   9223372036854775707      0x7fffffffffffff9b
```

Adding `0.01` forces this value to be rounded to double-precision floating point before the addition.  The two closest values that are representable in double-precision are:

```
   9223372036854774784      0x7ffffffffffffc00
   9223372036854775808      0x8000000000000000
```

Because `sys.maxint - 100` is closer to the second (larger) value, it rounds up.  Adding `0.01` gives:

```
   9223372036854775808.01   0x8000000000000000.028f5c28f5c...
```

which is not representable in double-precision, so it is rounded again, to:

```
   9223372036854775808      0x8000000000000000
```

So the value of `sys.maxint - 100 + 0.01` **is** actually larger than the value of `sys.maxint`.  However, in many modern languages, comparison between an integer and a float forces the integer value to be converted to floating point before the comparison takes place; if this were the case in python, `sys.maxint` would be rounded up to the same value, and they would compare equal.  It seems that this is not the case in Python.  I'm not familiar with the details of python numerics, but this is an interesting curiosity of the language.

Comment: You are right, `assert float(sys.maxint) > (sys.maxint - 100 + 0.01)`

Comment: You're correct:  Python goes out of its way to give correct results for mixed-type comparisons.  Without this, Python containers (sets, dicts) would be in trouble, since the `==` relation is used to determine container membership.

Answer (score 12):

This is probably due to loss of precision for very large floating point values. (the adding of `0.01` converts the right-hand-side to float).

**Edit:** I have tried to come up with an exact explanation of what happens here, but to no avail. So I [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431517/can-someone-explain-this-floating-point-behavior) about it.

Comment: Precisely. See also the output of `int(sys.maxint - 100 + 0.01)` on 64-bit: `9223372036854775808L` (instead of `...807L`)

Comment: Except for Windows 64 bit machines where sys.maxint always is 2**32/2-1 because the long type is only 32 bits signed.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y, what do you mean by `loose 11 bits of precision`, are those 11 bits set to zero or some random bit string?

Comment: @Saturo: I am not exactly sure (my explanation is more of a guess), but *since the bits are just truncated, it is as if they were 0, so the result is lower than the actual number*.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y, In that case, `sys.maxint` the integer should not be smaller than `sys.maxint - 100 + 0.01` the float. So I guess it may be some random bit string or a string of `1`s, which may depend on hardware implementation.

Comment: @Saturo: You are right, my explanation is incorrect there. I do not really know why exactly this happens too, sorry.

Comment: @Satoru Logic: He meant lose, not loose. Those 11 bits can't be "set" to anything, they don't exist. You have 64 precision passengers to fit on a approx-53 precision-passenger bus. 11 passengers miss out. Those 11 bit positions in a float (still a 64-seat bus) are used for the exponent and sign bit. Note that the leading precision bit in a float is 1 by definition and thus doesn't need a seat.

Answer (score 3):

at least on my machine it is not

```
In [7]: import sys

In [8]: sys.maxint < (sys.maxint - 100 + 0.01)
Out[8]: False
```

Comment: Needs 64-bit to see it, on 32-bit the number is too small for the float to lose the necessary amount of precision.