# Can someone explain this floating-point behavior?

Tags: python, floating-point, ieee-754

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429860/why-is-sys-maxint-sys-maxint-100-0-01-in-python), I was trying to find out *what exactly happens there* (my answer was more intuitive, but I cannot exactly understand the why of it).

I believe it comes down to this (running 64 bit Python):

```
>>> sys.maxint
9223372036854775807
>>> float(sys.maxint)
9.2233720368547758e+18
```

Python uses the IEEE 754 floating-point representation, which effectively has 53 bits for the significant. However, as far as I understand it, the significant in the above example would require 57 bits (56 if you drop the implied leading 1) to be represented. Can someone explain this discrepancy?

Comment: Remember, floating point numbers in Python are stored in *binary*, not decimal.

Comment: @Gabe.  Exactly:  what you see is *not* what you get.  float(sys.maxint) is a float, stored in binary internally, whose value is exactly 2**63, or sys.maxint + 1, or to be exact, 9223372036854775808.0.  What's displayed when you type `float(sys.maxint)` is merely a *decimal* approximation to that floating-point value.  Python never prints more than 17 significant digits for the `repr` of a floating-point value;  to print the exact value here would require 19 significant digits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the following will help clear things up:

```
>>> hex(int(float(sys.maxint)))
'0x8000000000000000L'
```

This shows that `float(sys.maxint)` is in fact a power of 2. Therefore, in binary its mantissa is exactly `1`. In IEEE 754 the leading `1.` is implied, so in the machine representation this number's mantissa consists of all zero bits.

In fact, the IEEE bit pattern representing this number is as follows:

```
0x43E0000000000000
```

Observe that only the first three nibbles (the sign and the exponent) are non-zero. The significand consists entirely of zeroes. As such it doesn't require 56 (nor indeed 53) bits to be represented.

Answer (score 2):

You're wrong. It requires 1 bit.

```
>>> (9.2233720368547758e+18).hex()
'0x1.0000000000000p+63'
```

Comment: Very funny. That single 1 bit isn't much use without all the other zeros.

Comment: @David: Sure, but they're *all* zeros, and can remain so as far as the horizon and until the end of time.

Comment: @David: What's the difference between `1` and `1.000000000000000`?

Comment: Hmm, I guess this is a case where less precision would be better - using fewer bits would erase the discrepancy. Not very practical, though.

Answer (score 1):

When you convert sys.maxint to a float or double, the result is exactly 0x1p63, because the significand contains only 24 or 53 bits (including the implicit bit), so the trailing bits cause a round up.  (sys.maxint is 2^63 - 1, and rounding it up produces 2^63.)

Then, when you print this float, some subroutine formats it as a decimal numeral.  To do this, it calculates digits to represent 2^63. The fact that it is able to print 9.2233720368547758e+18 does not imply that the original number contains bits that would distinguish it from 9.2233720368547759e+18.  It simple means that the bits in it do represent 9.2233720368547758e+18 (approximately).  In fact, the next representable floating-point number in double precision is 9223372036854777856 (approximately 9.2233720368547778e+18), which is 2^63 + 2048.  So the low 11 bits of these integers are not present in the double.  The formatter merely displays the number as if those bits are zero.